# Word for fell asleep unconsciously

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Is there a single word to express - I feel asleep unconsciously or like when it happens you just
want to relax on bed but fell asleep. How do you communicate that efficiently with a single word 
or better way

Comment: Not a single word, but saying, "I [**nodded off**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/nod-off)," means this.

Comment: One inevitably lapses into unconsciousness when falling asleep. A more appropriate adverb would be **inadvertently**. I write as a practised performer in the field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrasal verb [doze off](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/doze-off) is appropriate:

> to go to sleep, especially when you did not intend to

Comment: Also *nod* off…

Answer (score 0):

The phrase [pass out](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pass-out)

> to become unconscious